# why the compiler tell me it's irrefutable?

Tags: rust

I wanna to implement when `e` type is `Notfound` create  file

```
    let file = File::open("pass.ini");
    match file {
        Ok(f) => {
            todo!()
        }
        Err(e) => {
            if let e = NotFound {
                File::create("pass.ini");
            }
        }
    }
```

but use `cargo check`,compiler tell me this:

```
warning: irrefutable `if let` pattern
  --> src/main.rs:51:16
   |
51 |             if let e = NotFound {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(irrefutable_let_patterns)]` on by default
   = note: this pattern will always match, so the `if let` is useless
   = help: consider replacing the `if let` with a `let`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr, use `if e.kind() == NotFound {`

In `if let e = NotFound {`, the left hand side (`e`) is the pattern you are matching the right hand side (`NotFound`) against. As `e` will match everything, it will always be true. Confusingly, the `e` in your statement is not the variable that was bound by the `e` in the match arm.

You could also include the condition in the match arm,

```
let file = File::open("pass.ini");
match file {
    Ok(f) => {
        todo!()
    }
    Err(e) if e.kind() == NotFound => File::create("pass.ini"),
    Err(e) => todo!()
}
```